# Online (My)SQL tool to escape strings for use in queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I need to put a number of texts into my MySQL database via a manual query. The texts contain quotes, newlines, comment dashes ('--') and probably other syntax errors. Is there an online tool where I can paste in raw text and convert it to the query-escaped version?

Comment: Not that I know of, but to create one of your own shouldnt be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.de/search?q=sql+escape+string+online) gives me

http://www.freeformatter.com/string-escaper.html
and
http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-escape.html

Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: Will try. I couldn't find them by Googling "MySQL string escape" though, which returned only links to the PHP function :/. Hopefully this question will fix that for others.

Comment: I believe PHP is the most infamous language in this respect, so it's no surprise, that most links point there :-)

Comment: This one: http://www.freeformatter.com/sql-escape.html (the first one I tried) works well.

Comment: The free formatter sql-escape doesn't escape backslashes (\\) properly. It should be doubled as well.

Comment: http://addslashes.onlinephpfunctions.com seems quite good